# Getting parent node through child node in Firebase Realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

In my app in Android studio I've coded for allowing users to book appointment with doctors. So if the doctor accepts the appointment, I want to change the value of child node "Status". For that I need the value of the parent node which is [image: this] .

For that I tried using `String currentUserId = ds.getKey();` ,but ds,getKey() gives the value "Patient" which is a child node of the required parent node. So how do I get the key (circled red in image)?

```
patRef = database.getReference().child("Patient Appointments");

patRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String pat = ds.child("Patient").getValue(String.class);

                if(pat.equals(Email)){
                    HashMap update= new HashMap();
                    update.put("Status","Appointment on "+date);

                    String currentUserId = ds.getKey();
                    Toast.makeText(DoctorNotification.this, currentUserId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    patRef.child(currentUserId).updateChildren(update).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Object o) {
                            Toast.makeText(DoctorNotification.this, "Appointment accepted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    flag1="True";
                }

            }

            if(flag1.equals("False")){
                Toast.makeText(DoctorNotification.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: ds.getRef().updateChildren(update).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
 works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered yourself, you can update the current node in the loop with:

```
ds.getRef().child(currentUserId).updateChildren(update)
```

---

I wanted to provide an additional comment on the approach you take to finding the node to update. Right now you load all `Patient Appointments` to find one of them, which is going to be inefficient - especially one you start adding more appointment.

### Use a query to only load the node for the current patient

One way to improve this is by using a query to only retrieve the appointment of the `Patient` you're looking for. That'd look something like this:

```
patRef = database.getReference().child("Patient Appointments");

Query patientQuery = patRef.orderByChild("Patient").equalTo(Email);

patientQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    ...
```

And you can then remove the `if(pat.equals(Email)){` from within the `onComplete`.

### Use a query on both Patient and Status fields

One smaller optimization after this is that you probably only need to check the appointments that are pending. For that you'd like a query like above, but then on two fields.

This is not something the Firebase Realtime Database natively supports, but you can emulate it by adding a composite field to your data: `"Patient_Status": "Elise@doc.com_Pending"`. The query would then become:

```
patRef.orderByChild("Patient_Status").equalTo(Email+"_Pending");
```

### Store the key of the node in your UI

The final improvement assumes that the doctor is actually shown a list of all (pending) appointments and then click to accept one or more of them. In such a scenario you already read all the appointments from the database to show them in the user interface.

If you store the key of each appointment in a (hidden) field in the user interface, you can then use that key when the doctor clicks it, and the entire update operation can become as simple as:

```
patRef
  .child("keyOfTheAppointmentTheDoctorClicked")
  .child("Status")
  .setValue("Appointment on "+date);
```